# Overload operator for byte[]

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I want to overload the <, >, <= and >= operators for operands of type byte[] in C#. So I found about the "one of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type" error the hard way. Anyways, I can't seem to be able to inherit from byte[] and I don't want to encapsulate a byte[] in another class (sound like too much overhead). Is there a way around it? Maybe using Extension Methods? or is that complete insane?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No real way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No real way to do so. – Mehrdad Afshari

Given `byte[] a, b`:

One could use extension methods to define "wordy" operators as `a.GreaterThan(b)`, which is really just a short way of writing `MyByteArray.GreaterThan(a, b)`.

However, it's *not* possible to define an operator if neither (possibly the same) type in the expression cannot be modified to add such.

A trivial wrapper wouldn't add much overhead (or benefit?) though: `MyByteArray.Rich(a) > b`, where `Rich` returned a type with the `>` operator defined.

Implicit/explicit casts are also out because `a` still cannot be modified, as [custom] casts are defined on the source expression, not the target expression.